# Extracting part of string using regular expressions

Tags: regex, r, string

I’m struggling to get a bit of regular expressions code to work.  I have a long list of strings that I need to partially extract.  I need only strings that starting with “WER” and I only need the last part of the string commencing (including) on the letter.

```
test <- c("abc00012Z345678","WER0004H987654","WER12400G789456","WERF12","0-0Y123")
```

Here is the line of code which is working but only for one letter. However in my list of strings it can have any letter.

```
ifelse(substr(test,1,3)=="WER",gsub("^.*H.*?","H",test),"")
```

What I’m hoping to achieve is the following:

```
H987654
G789456
F12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following pattern with `gsub`:

```
> gsub("^(?:WER.*([a-zA-Z]\\d*)|.*)$", "\\1", test)
[1] ""        "H987654" "G789456" "F12"     ""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN0cG1/1)

This pattern matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:`  - start of an alternation group with 2 alternatives:

  - `WER.*([a-zA-Z]\\d*)` - `WER` char sequence followed with 0+ any characters (`.*`) as many as possible up to the last letter (`[a-zA-Z]`) followed by 0+ digits (`\\d*`) (replace with `\\d+` to match 1+ digits, to require at least 1 digit)
  - `|` - or
  - `.*  - any 0+ characters
- `)$` - closing the alternation group and match the end of string with `$`.

With `str_match` from *stringr*, it is even tidier:

```
> library(stringr)
> res <- str_match(test, "^WER.*([a-zA-Z]\\d*)$")
> res[,2]
[1] NA        "H987654" "G789456" "F12"     NA       
>
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN0cG1/2)

If there are newlines in the input, add `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern: `res <- str_match(test, "(?s)^WER.*([a-zA-Z]\\d*)$")`.

Comment: Just FYI: `"^.*H.*?"` matches the whole chunk of a string from its beginning till the last `H`, and stops right there as `.*?` at the end does not consume/return any characters (because it is a lazy subpattern and can match an empty string, so it matches the empty location after `H` and calls it a day). This matched chunk is replaced with "H" by `gsub`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want empty strings or NA for strings that don't start with "WER", you could try the following approach:

```
sub(".*([A-Z].*)$", "\\1", test[grepl("^WER", test)])
#[1] "H987654" "G789456" "F12"
```